# Change the MySite Blog Site Title SP2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, my-site, blog

When users provision a Blog on their SharePoint 2013 MySite, the Site Title is called "Blog".  Thus when a crawl is done, the search results say **"Blog"** as the title.  Is there a way to change the title to say something like "DisplayName's" Blog ?

Bismarck

Answer (score 4):

You change it, there are couple of ways.

**Method 1 using the GUI, this should be done by every user.**

> via site setting Site settings >> Click on Title, description, and
>   icon Link under "Look and Feel", Change the name and description as
>   per your requirements!

**Method 2:** You can use the powershell.

```
    #Get the Web
$Web= Get-SPWeb "http://your-sharepoint-site.com"

#Set the Title & Description
$Web.Title = "Marketing Portal"
$Web.Description = "Marketing Portal"

#You can change the Quick Launch/Treeview navigation also (If its not a Publishing site):
$Web.TreeViewEnabled = $True
#Update the changes
$web.Update()
```

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/02/change-title-description-and-icon-with-powershell.html

**Method 3:** create an event receiver once a user provisioned his blog site your event fired and change the title according to your requirement.